# Download file in Safari with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to download a file with the filename in Safari using JavaScript/jQuery?

I've created an anchor element with a url that looks like this:

```
<a href="linkToFile" download="fileName.csv">Download File</a>
```

Unfortunately, the download attribute hasn't been implemented in Safari yet (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a). So when the file downloads in Safari (my version is 8), the file name is "unknown".

Is there a workaround so that when the file downloads in Safari (8+), it will have the filename?

I downloaded a file from dropbox in Safari and it worked fine, filename and all. How'd they do that??

Comment: safari can download from a server just fine, with a content-disposition http header...

Comment: The content disposition on the link is "attachment; filename=filename.csv"...but I'm still not sure how to download this properly using javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in case anyone runs across this problem. jQuery fileDownload works fine in Safari event though the developer doesn't officially list it as a supported and tested browser. https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload

Comment: Note that the developer themselves explicitly recommend _not_ using that package any longer, and it doesn't appear to be maintained: https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload#2019-modern-browsers-update